# How to ensure just one instance of a Task is running?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a "long running function" that needs to be triggered on a timer, and which I would also like to be able to triggered by button click. While the task is running, the button will switch to a 'Cancel' button. I only want a single instance of the task running at a time. I've made the task a private variable so that the timer can check the `IsCompleted` status of the task. To do this I created a private variable

```
private Task sync;
```

I then have a function that does the task

```
private async Task syncUsers()
{
    //
}
```

Right now, on button click, I have the variable assigned to the function

```
sync = syncUsers();
await sync;
```

It seems like when the task is completed, that's it. How do I restart the Task/function? I tried using a Task factory and async delegate and did not work.

```
sync = Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate { await syncStudents(); });
await sync;
```

I have a feeling I'm going about it completely wrong but not sure where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart the task"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad the `syncUsers` function needs to run again.

Comment: Aren't you running it again in the button click event handler?

Comment: @YacoubMassad That is the button click handler. I only want to run one instance of it at a time, so I check in the timer that `.IsCompleted`.

Comment: You won't be able to Re-start. You'll have to create new task

Comment: So all you are trying to do is prevent parallel executions? Is this why you save the task in a field? What you can do simply is disable the button in the start of the event handler, and then re-enable it after you await the task (you should enable it in a finally block to handle the case when the method throws an exception).

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes I am trying to prevent parallel executions. I already disable the button. But the sync function is also on a timer and should run periodically, and after the task has run once, I am having trouble running it again.

Comment: Please include all relevant details in the question. Talk about the original problem.

Comment: Couldn't you just simply test sync for `null` and not start a new one if it is set? Only create and and start a new task if sync is null and have the task reset the field when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to Re-start. You'll have to create new task. If you want to support multiple parallel task executions, instead of `Task sync`, do `List<Task> syncTasks` and then do `syncTasks.Add(syncUsers())`. you can then `await` on `Task.WhenAll(syncTasks)`.

Unless i'm misunderstanding the question

**Edit**
To periodically run the sync task do something like this:

```
private System.Threading.Timer _syncTimer;
private bool _isRunning;
private int refreshInterval = 30;

public YourClass(){
    _syncTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback);
}

public void StartSyncTimer(){
    _syncTimer.Change(0, 0);
}

private async Task SyncUsers(){
        //
}
private void TimerCallback(object userState){
    _isRunning = true;
    var task = SyncUsers();
    task.ContinueWith(t => {
        _isRunning = false;
        _syncTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(refreshInterval), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
    });
}
```

Then in your Click handler you could do something like this:

```
if(!_isRunning){
    _syncTimer.Change(0,0);
}
```

**Explanation:** In the constructor we initialize a System.Threading.Timer instance that periodically executes `TimerCallback` method.

Then we add a public method to the class to start the timer execution immediately: _syncTimer.Change(0, 0). Here the first zero means delay before first execution (immediately) and the second zero means repeat interval. It's also a zero meaning it will not auto repeat.

However in the continuation of the SyncUsers task, we reschedule the timer for whatever period you want.

Within the timer callback we also set _IsRunning to true to alert any interested parties of the status, and then on the task's completion we set it back to true.

Behavior of the above code would be: If the sync task was started by the timer, click would not do anything since _isRunning will be true; If the sync was scheduled by the completion for after `refreshIntervals` the click would execute the sync immediately and then the completion would reschedule the sync for a later time.

**Disclaimer:** I have not actually ran the code above, but this is something I've done hundreds of times and could be made to work with a little more effort.

Comment: I don't want multiple parallel tasks, I want exactly one of these tasks at a time.

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve? When would you want the task to restart?

Comment: It must run periodically, but should also be able to be triggered by button click. But if its already running, then we don't want it to start again or something.

Comment: What happens if the periodic sync is in progress and someone clicks the sync button? Would you want the prior task to be canceled or the button click not handled?

Comment: I intend to change the button to a 'Cancel' when sync is running (although that is not implemented yet).

Comment: How do you run periodic syncs now?

Comment: Using a timer Tick-its not very implemented yet, I don't think I've let the timer run more than once yet.

Comment: @Nils Guillermin - I have updated my answer with a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
private Task sync;
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
private Task syncUsers()
{
    lock (syncLock)
    {
        if (this.sync == null || this.sync.IsCompleted)
        {
            this.sync = ...
        }
    }

    return this.sync;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing 'this.sync = ...' should read 'this.sync = await (...)'

but you can't call await inside a lock.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say that when you create your task, you do something like

```
Task task = new Task(()=>{ DoStuff(); });
```

What you need to do, is not keep the task for later execution. You need to keep the delegate, and create another task later on, using the same delegate.

In case you're unsure about how, look up [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx), it might give you ideas.